# Better tree structure

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```js
class Category {
  constructor(
     readonly _title: string,
  ) { }

  get title() {
    return this._title
  }
}

const categories = {
  get pets() {
    const pets = new Category('Pets')

    return {
      get dishes() {
        const dishes = new Category('Dishes')

        return dishes
      }
    }
  },
  get cloth() {
    const cloth = new Category('Cloth')

    return {
      get accessories() {
        const accessories = new Category('Accessories')

        return accessories
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use it like this

`const product = new Product(categories.pets.dishes)`

Its pretty good, but on frontend I should render this like tree:

```
<ul>
  {Object.entries(categories).map(
    ([slug, category]) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={slug}>
          <li>{category.title}</li> // problem here
            <ul>
              {Object.entries(category).map(([s, c]) => {
                return <li key={s}>{c.title}</li>
              })}
            </ul>
         </React.Fragment>
       )
  })}
</ul>
```

How can I get the name of the parent category? What's the best way to design this?

Comment: Introduce a `parent` member into the `Category` class?

Comment: What is `Product`? You assign to `product`, but then never use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that in `categories.pets` you create an instance `pets`, but  then do nothing with it. It is lost in oblivion. Instead you create another object by using an object literal (that is not an instance of `Category`) and return *that*. Obviously that object does not have a `title`...

For this to work, *add* the `dishes` getter to the `pets` object you just created, like so:

```
  get pets() {
    const pets = new Category('Pets');
    
    Object.defineProperty(pets, "dishes", {
      get() {
        const dishes = new Category('Dishes');
        return dishes
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });
    
    return pets;
  },
```

Apply the same fix to the second getter.

Secondly, in your inner loop in the JSX code, you will also iterate the `_title` property. You probably don't want to include that in your output. So either change the `Category` class to use a private field `#title` instead of `_title` (if your environment supports that syntax) or else, exclude properties that start with an underscore from your loop. For instance, by calling `.filter`:

```
              {Object.entries(category).filter(([s]) => s[0] !== "_")
                                       .map(([s, c]) => {
                return <li key={s}>{c.title}</li>
              })}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but now inside `pets` I can define two `dishes` and this is not good, do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Playground
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBcCmBzA9gJwJ7QN4ChpoBiBASwRCQC5oIEMyA7FfQ6YNJ%20jAV2ASYAFOyLlKNOg2YoANOwCUeUdAQALMhAB0pClWgBeVXqTsAvmyIokCYxKFKCRIhhu8MTVRu26J5-Bb4nNy2wIiomGRIMEZO0Na2AA42EA7Kzhxc9NDJCDHQTEgA7nDh6NhCAOQACimVCpbOAPIARgBWSAJaACZIAGbMSNUYaMkYCFhCuRCy0ABE3Zpq0XOzcRkJaesZmSHQixDL%20YUl8Mjlk5UAIkvR9Y070K4I7p4HRypEZvKPSEy8AFskBgwC0qLQGLwkD8dsEBih3KDwao%20NCVGYGipWh0ur0BoVhqNgRMpilZgtbhBVukdptHJ9nMFsu9ooYCsVSudMJcAOojFjQG6HO6Yx4uNwefaUhnfBl-QHApGSSFox5wsgIkFg5WomFfUXOZ6vHIpczyMxAA

Comment: I don't know what you mean. An object can never have the same property twice. If you define it a second time, it overwrites the first. That is how it is supposed to work. And I don't understand why you would program it like that. It makes the first call of `defineProperty` obsolete.